# How to convert a word to an array of characters

Tags: php

Can anyone help me? I want to convert a word to an array.

**example:**

```
$word = "hello"
```

and I want to convert it to an array like this:

```
$wordarray = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
```

The size of the array is automatically set by the length of the word

Is that possible?

Comment: use `str_split` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Comment: well how to convert the space to underscore (_), is possible to use 'contains' thing?

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen I knew there had to be a dupe somewhere...

Comment: @Nick If you've a gold medal in PHP, you can actually close it (I don't).

Comment: `str_split(str_replace(' ', '_', $word));`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen still working on that... only about 1/2 way there...

Comment: @Nick well tanks for help, its works

Comment: No worries @Wisnu, glad to help and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

use str_split() like

```
str_split('hello');
```